# Is there a difference between prepending a name-value-pair to a command and using env in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, env

Let's say I invoke `A=B command` and `env A=B command` in `bash`. Is there any situation where there might be a difference between both invokations?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They serve the same purpose (pass the given env vars to the command). However a few notable differences:

```
A=B command
```

is a shell (Bourne/POSIX/rc) construct.

For instance, you can do:

```
A=B find . -exec cmd '{}' +
```

or:

```
find . -exec env A=B cmd '{}' +
```

But you can't do:

```
find . -exec A=B cmd '{}' +
```

Because `find` is not invoking a shell to run that command.

On the other hand, `env` being an external command, you can't do:

```
f() { ...; }
env A=B f
```

or:

```
env A=B eval '...'
```

Also:

```
A=B cmd
```

works only with env vars that are valid *shell* variable names. You need `env` for any other env var name:

```
env 'my var=foo' cmd...
```

`bash` resets the `_` variable:

```
bash-4.3$ _=xxx env | grep '^_='
_=/usr/bin/env
bash-4.3$ env _=xxx env | grep '^_='
_=xxx
```

In `zsh`, `ARGV0` and `STTY` have special meanings in that context:

```
STTY=-echo cat
```

Runs `cat` with terminal `echo` disabled. And:

```
ARGV0=foo cmd
```

runs `cmd` with `foo` as its `argv[0]`.

If you don't want that special processing, you have to use `env`.

Note that `sudo` supports:

```
sudo A=B cmd
```

It's not using the shell or `env` to do that. It does it by itself.

It can pass variables with any name except those starting with `-`.

Assignment is a shell construct whereas an equal sign in the argument of `env` has no special meaning to the shell, so `A=$B cmd` is safe whereas `env A="$B" cmd` (or `sudo A="$B" cmd`) require double quotes.

The `A=B cmd` syntax is only supported in the shells of the Bourne and `rc` families (not `es` though). In shells of the `csh` or `fish` families for instance, you have to resort to `env`.